# Attempting to point to an image through a mySQL varchar string

Tags: php, mysql

So, I know I have the right idea, but I can't for the life of me get the syntax right. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the image file which is stored in a site folder, to point to a particular varchar value in my mySQL database (emp_thumb).

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?id="
    .$row['emp_id']."\">"
    .$row['emp_lname'].", "
    .$row['emp_fname'].
    <img src="images/'.$row['emp_thumb'].'"></a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem, the image is broken?, the code does nothing?

Comment: Put a ' in front of <img, remove " from '"></a></li>" and close the previous string with '

Comment: Can you provide same sample data, and folder structure? Or check if the ouput of row['emp_thumb'] matches the file structure, with an simple print/echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need fix quotes in the last line. It might be helpful to use an editor which will highlight your mistakes. Or pay attention to the error messages which are generated. They will give you clues. If you don't have error checking on, do so by adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to your code.
.

```
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($employees)) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"index.php?id="
    .$row['emp_id']."\">"
    .$row['emp_lname'].", "
    .$row['emp_fname'].
    "<img src='images/" . $row['emp_thumb'] . "'></a></li>";
}
?>
```

Comment: This works. Thank you! I'm just learning PHP so it's taking a bit getting used to the syntax.